# The size of freshly new Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, filesize

I created a new project in Android Studio and nothing more (by that I mean having a main activity which does nothing). But when I checked the size of a project folder on my disc I saw it tooks over 40MB! I looked into the project file's content and I saw there folders for which I have questions about:

1) What is the purpose of folder (and it's content) MyProgram/build/generated? Is there a possibility to not create it? (I would save 30MB on my disc by deleting it.)

2) I presume that I shouldn't delete MyProgram/app/build/intermediates so I'm wondering if it'll grow with development of MyProgram? And if the answer is "yes" then how much the size will change? (It tooks almost 10MB now and I'm afraid what will happen when I do something more in my code.)

Comment: These file sizes are tiny, nothing to worry about on a modern machine

Comment: Oh, so it seems all of that I programmed during my studies were just small. Thank you for relieving me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of folder (and it's content) MyProgram/build/generated?

For a module (e.g., `app/`) `build/generated/` contains Java source code and other files that are generated as part of the build process.

If you are referring to the `build/generated/` that appears off of the project root directory, that contains... a JAR. This is an odd place for the build tools to put this particular type of file.

> Is there a possibility to not create it?

I don't think so. However, its contents will not go into your APK file. If your development machine is so short on disk space that a 30MB file makes a difference, you will have a very difficult time doing Android development.

> I'm wondering if it'll grow with development of MyProgram?

Most likely.

> how much the size will change?

That will vary by the size of your app (your code, third-party libraries that you add, etc.) and changes to the build tools over time. It is impossible to tell you exactly how large it will get.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

The size from the basic "Hello world" is the minium, doesnt matter if the size is 30 mb or more, is just about the development code, when you generate de APK to share and install your app the basic "Hello world"  the size is 2.5 - 3.5 mb. depends from the version of android studio are you using actually, the last version form android studio add somethings.

How i say the real size from you apk is the important, for example if you create the drawables resources for the diferents densities when you install the app just keep 1 density resources, an application size average 7 - 10 mb. A simple app is weird is the size exceeds this numbers.

1)   build/ directory and build/intermediates/ is output of the build process,contains Java source code, do not delete.

2) repeat the 1) answer, do not delete.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and clear instructions. :)